# What is my grandfather's shoulder patch?

Tags: military, 1950s

This is a photograph of my grandfather...  his DD214 shows his last unit as Co C 52d AIB APO 221

[image]

Comment: Since the question is about a relative of yours, please add information on the country he served in, as well as service branch, etc.

Comment: "Co C 52d AIB APO 221" is *Company C, 52nd Armored Infantry Battalion, Army Post Office 221*. The date would be useful. Note that [your grandfather's company was involved in saving some 9th Armored tankers near Limburg](http://www.lonesentry.com/gi_stories_booklets/9tharmored/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

The patch looks like its from the [52nd Armored Infantry Battalion,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/52nd_Infantry_Regiment_(United_States)) matching the " Co C 52d AIB" from the papers.

> It was redesignated for the 52d Armored Infantry Regiment on 29 September 1942. The insignia was redesignated for the 52d Armored Infantry Battalion on 6 January 1944. It was redesignated for the 52d Infantry Regiment on 31 October 1958.
> […]
> After the armistice, the six-point Red Star was adopted as the division insignia on 19 November 1918. This six-point Red Star became a part of the 52d Infantry's crest to mark the regiment's first combat with the 6th Division.

Its insignia as used on the shoulder patch is a just six-pointed star.

> [image: 52d Infantry Regimental Distinctive Unit Insignia (DUI)]

---

Thanks to the excellent eyes of [user @Andrew](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/13158/andrew), we also have a good estimate on the insignia on the cap and shoulder strap :

> The cap badge seems to match the [20th Infantry Regiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20th_Infantry_Regiment_(United_States)), which was assigned to 6th Infantry Division until 1956 - and 6th ID would have had the same star badge. The division was a training unit at the time - is it possible he was there before being sent to 52nd AIB, and this was taken then?

[image]

And for completeness, user @Schwern notes that the data on the DD214

> "Co C 52d AIB APO 221" is Company C, 52nd Armored Infantry Battalion, Army Post Office 221. The date would be useful. Note that [your grandfather's company was involved in saving some 9th Armored tankers near Limburg.](http://www.lonesentry.com/gi_stories_booklets/9tharmored/index.html)

Comment: Can you explicate the symbol on cap  and on the shoulder strap?

Comment: Yeah, those are throwing me completely.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't think that it's flat-out the patch for the 6th Infantry Div, which is just the 6-pointed star?

Comment: The cap badge seems to match the [20th Infantry Regiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20th_Infantry_Regiment_(United_States)), which was assigned to 6th Infantry Division until 1956 - and 6th ID would have had the same star badge. The division was a training unit at the time - is it possible he was there before being sent to 52nd AIB, and this was taken then?

Comment: @Andrew As far as I see it, you're most probably spot on with that. While strictly speaking 'not what is asked', it is nice info & obviously already asked about here in comments. Do you want to edit that in, have it edited in, or write/add your own answer? It's too good to stay in comments… ;)

Comment: @LаngLаngС please, feel free to add it here :-)

Comment: @AmorphousBlob Their papers are for 52nd Armored Infantry Battalion which served with 9th Armored Div in WW2, not 6th Infantry Div.